# Modify the string to a CommaSeparated Line - Apache PIG

Tags: string, group-by, apache-pig

After the execution of my PIG Script:

```
FILE = LOAD 'PATH_FILE'  
    USING PigStorage(',') as 
      (ID:Long, 
      MUNICIPALITY:String,
          CITY:Int,
          COUNTRY:Int,
          COMPANY:Long,
          BRAND:Long,
          DATE:Chararray,
          STOCK_NAME:Chararray,
          STOCK_SIZE:Double,
          STOCK_AMOUNT:Double);

DATA = GROUP FILE BY (ID,MUNICIPALITY);

GRP_DATA = FOREACH DATA GENERATE group as STOCK_ID, FILE.COMPANY as COMPANY, FILE.BRAND as BRAND,FILE.DATE as DATE, FILE.STOCK_NAME AS STOCK_NAME, SUM(FILE.STOCK_AMOUNT) as STOCK_AMOUNT;

RANKING = rank GRP_DATA by STOCK_NAME,COMPANY,BRAND;

STORE RANKING INTO 'PATH_DESTINATION USING PigStorage(',');
```

I'm getting this output:

```
1,(7287026502032012,18),{(706)},{(101200010)},{(17286)},{(oz)},2.5
```

How can I using PIG can obtain this line:

```
 1,7287026502032012,18,706,101200010,17286,oz,2.5
```

Is possible to return this?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Try `A = LOAD 'input.txt' as line;  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(line,'[(){}]+','');  
dump B;  `

Comment: thanks :D That resolves my problem!

Comment: Great, I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a regex to remove all `(`, `)`, `{`, and `}`:

```
[(){}]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qH6qA0/1).

In PIG:

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' as line;  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(line,'[(){}]+',''); 
dump B;
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).